# Границы области кластеризации PruneCluster

Tags: javascript

Столкнулся с такой проблемой: пытаюсь сделать отображение области кластеризации в PruneCluster, как в markerclustergroup (отвечает свойство ShowCoverageOnHover). 
[image: ShowCoverageOnHover:true]

Уже всю голову изломал, но чего-то так и не получается.
Если кто сталкивался с такой проблемой, помогите советом или кодом, пожалуйста:)

Comment: Вы хоть расскажите, что это за библиотека. Как вы возможно знаете, в мире существует больше одной библиотеки по работе с картами.

Comment: Библиотека Leaflet